# Advance slug/url parameterization (incl. transliteration) library in Python

Tags: python, url, slug

I'm new to Python and am looking for a slug/url parameterization library that offers similar function to that in the Ruby [Stringex library](https://github.com/rsl/stringex).  For example:

```
# A simple prelude
"simple English".to_url => "simple-english"
"it's nothing at all".to_url => "its-nothing-at-all"
"rock & roll".to_url => "rock-and-roll"

# Let's show off
"$12 worth of Ruby power".to_url => "12-dollars-worth-of-ruby-power"
"10% off if you act now".to_url => "10-percent-off-if-you-act-now"

# You don't even wanna trust Iconv for this next part
"kick it en Français".to_url => "kick-it-en-francais"
"rock it Español style".to_url => "rock-it-espanol-style"
"tell your readers 你好".to_url => "tell-your-readers-ni-hao"
```

I've come across webhelpers.text.urlify, which claims to do this however- the results weren't close.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [slugify](https://github.com/zacharyvoase/slugify), which is based on [Django's own slugify template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#slugify), but with [NFKD normalization](http://unicode.org/faq/normalization.html). Here's the relevant code:

```
re.sub(r'[-\s]+', '-',
            unicode(
                re.sub(r'[^\w\s-]', '',
                    unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', string)
                    .encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
                .strip()
                .lower()))
```

It's not nearly as powerful as Ruby's Stringex, but you could easily extend it to expand those ampersands, dollar symbols, etc. Take a look at [Unidecode](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode), a Python port of `Text::Unidecode` Perl module, the same thing Stringex uses for Unicode transliteration.

Comment: I think this code is **way** inferior to what stringex does. It doesn't even do transliteration. `möp` turns into `mop` instead of `moep` for example.